# Video not playing in server (Django)

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, html5-video

I am fairly new to Django and currently I'm making a Youtube Clone to understand Django in depth.
So the problem I'm facing right now is that I can't seem to get the video to play in the server. I've spent a lot of time trying but can't seem to find an answer!
I'll provide what I think relates to my problem;

**1) Template**

```
` video.html
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="{{ video.path }}" type="video/mp4">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>`
```

**2) views.py**

```
 `class VideoView(View):
    template_name = 'base/video.html'

    def get(self, request, id):
        #fetch video from DB by ID
        video_by_id = Video.objects.get(id=id)
        BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
        video_by_id.path = 'http://localhost:8000/get_video/'+video_by_id.path
        context = {'video':video_by_id}
        
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            print('user signed in')
            comment_form = CommentForm()
            context['form'] = comment_form

        
        comments = Comment.objects.filter(video__id=id).order_by('-datetime')[:5]
        print(comments)
        context['comments'] = comments
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)

class VideoFileView(View):
    
    def get(self, request, file_name):
        BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
        file = FileWrapper(open(BASE_DIR+'/'+file_name, 'rb'))
        response = HttpResponse(file, content_type='video/mp4')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename={}'.format(file_name)
        return response`
```

**3) models.py**

```
`class Video(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=300)
    path = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True ,blank=False, null=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
`
```

**4) urls.py**

```
` app_name = 'Youtube'
  urlpatterns = [
    path('home/', HomeView.as_view(), name='homeview'),
    path('login/', LoginView.as_view(), name='loginview'),
    path('register/', RegisterView.as_view(), name='register'),
    path('new_video/', NewVideo.as_view(), name='newvideo'),
    path('redirect/', Redirect.as_view(), name='redirect'),
    path('video/<int:id>', VideoView.as_view(), name='Videoview'),
    path('comment/', CommentView.as_view(), name='comment'),
    path('get_video/<file_name>', VideoFileView.as_view(), name='getvideo'),
]`
```

[This how it looks on the server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzKbY.png)

**Also the path to the video is as follows:
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Youtube Redesign\Config\video.mp4**

I tried making a Youtube Clone, I've gotten pretty far but currently I'm stuck because I can not figure out how to properly upload the video!!

Comment: Is there any error or warning logs in browser console? Also, check your network tab and tell if there any download requests for your file. Also, it would be usefull to see segment with video tag of loaded in browser html page.

Comment: It gives this error in terminal:
<QuerySet []>
[30/Mar/2023 15:38:59] "GET /video/14 HTTP/1.1" 200 14337
Not Found: /get_video/Q6UFSNRS5Pvideo.mp4
[30/Mar/2023 15:38:59] "GET /get_video/Q6UFSNRS5Pvideo.mp4 HTTP/1.1" 404 0

Apparently its attaching extra "Q6UFSNRS5P" to the video path.
The original video path is:
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Youtube Redesign\Config\video.mp4

Answer (score 0):

You get 404 error, because your url has a `.` symbol, which makes a completely new url path that is not specified in your urlpatterns.

It will be complicated to give you the best solution for this task, but to keep progressing, you can change your `VideoFileView` to this:

```
class VideoFileView(View):

    def get(self, request, file_name):
        BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
        file = FileWrapper(open(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, file_name), 'rb'))
        response = HttpResponse(file, content_type='video/mp4')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename={}'.format(file_name)
        return response`
```

It will support only mp4 files (is hardcoded to `open`) but it will fix your issue of `404 Not found` since your view will be used (you can check it with a `print`).

Comment: I replaced my existing VideoFileView() with the one you just now provided, however I'm now getting this error.

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\Youtube Redesign\\Config/video1.mp4.mp4'

Comment: If i remove '.mp4' from file = FileWrapper(open(f"{BASE_DIR}/{file_name}.mp4", 'rb')), it now gives me the error:   FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\Youtube Redesign\\Config/NBLX6X1TTPvideo.mp4',,,, for some reason its adding random characters like "NBLX6X1TTP" to the actual video path

Comment: I guess It's adding additional char because you save a new video by API and already have `video.mp4`  file in that folder, so django adds new chars to make filename unique.

Comment: I modified my code a little to include `os.path.join()`. Try adding it.

Comment: Still getting this:            FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\Youtube Redesign\\Config\\0NHCH0SMDWvideo1.mp4'

Comment: Ok, but where is 0NHCH0SMDWvideo1.mp4 located on your pc? I doubt its in your BASE_DIR. I guess you need to find where this file saved and specify it instead of BASE_DIR.

Comment: That's the thing there is no such file, the actual path to the video is: C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Youtube Redesign\Config\video.mp4,,,,,,, However, when I run the server it somehow attach's extra value to the path and stores it into the backend with the wrong path like this:   C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\Youtube Redesign\\Config\\0NHCH0SMDWvideo1.mp4,,,,,,,,, So when I run the server its looking for the video with the wrong path.